# XSS - double quote and backslash escaping

Tags: xss, reflected-xss

I'm currently testing my own XSS filter and don't know if I thought everything through, so I need some advice.

Let's say my code looks like this:

```
<script>
var test = {src: "test", layer: {"input": "USER INPUT", "event": "ready"}};
</script>
```

In this specific case, if I replace `\` with `\\` and `"` with `\"` is it possible to trick my filter? Of course the user input would be where USER INPUT is in my code.

Comment: Why don't you use an existing XSS filter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> In this specific case, if I replace `\` with `\\` and `"` with `\"` is it possible to trick my filter?

That's not sufficient, your filter is insecure.

E.g., one valid XSS attack vector would be `</script><svg onload=alert(1)>`, ending up with:

```
<script>
var test = {src: "test", layer: {"input": "</script><svg onload=alert(1)>", "event": "ready"}};
</script>
```

Since the XML (HTML) tree is parsed before any JS is evaluated, the closing script tag (`</script>`) will terminate the script despite being placed within a JS string.

Another problem with your filter are line breaks. If an attacker can insert a `0x0a` byte, they can break your script by causing a syntax error (since a double quoted string can't span multiple lines):

```
<script>
var test = {src: "test", layer: {"input": "
", "event": "ready"}};
</script>
```

If you're using PHP, a convenient filter function to work safely with user input inside JS is [`json_encode()`](https://secure.php.net/json_encode). From [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/110110/95381):

> With plain PHP a common and safe approach is to use
>   [`json_encode()`](https://secure.php.net/json_encode) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816787/json-php-to-javascript-safe-or-not/6817147#6817147). E.g.:
>
> ```
> var foo = <?php echo json_encode($foo, JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_APOS); ?>
> ```
>
> `json_encode()` returns the JSON representation of a value, hence it's
>   guaranteed to evaulate to a valid object in your JS code and you can
>   just assign it to a variable as shown. **But don't omit the additional
>   flags.** Depending on the context, an attacker could otherwise use
>   payloads like `</script>` to break out of the entire script tag.

Comment: Does json_encode escape </script> though?

Comment: @immibis Yes, with the correct flags! (That's why I linked [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110101/proper-way-to-protect-against-xss-when-output-is-directly-into-js-not-html/110110#110110) that addresses this aspect.)

Comment: Alternatively, it maybe be useful to use `<![CDATA[` tags instead of trying to escape your json.

Comment: @Matthew how does that help?

Comment: `<script>  /*<![CDATA[*/  var json = {"myvalue": "</script>"};  /*]]>*/ 
 </script>` works just fine, the entire contents of the script tag are treated as character data instead of html.  `alert(json["myvalue"]);` will now popup with `</script>`

Comment: @Matthew An attacker can just terminate the CDATA section.

Comment: That is correct, all you need to do is escape CDATA within your content block (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223652/is-there-a-way-to-escape-a-cdata-end-token-in-xml) and that will work for any content that you want to be treated as character content, regardless of the underlying content, be it json, xml, etc.

Comment: @Matthew: cdata? that would only affect xhtml pages, haven't seen any of those in a while...